# Suddenly, Android Studio debugger don't stop in breakpoints. How solve it?

Tags: android-studio, debugging

It is scary how this kind of problem swarms here at *Stackoverflow* and there doesn't seem to be any consistent solution.

I've read all stuff from *Stackoverflow* and nothing seems to solve this problem.

I have *Android Studio 4.02* and *Windows 7*, and I use `Kotlin`

Suddenly, the *Android Studio* don't stop in breakpoints anymore.

I've tried everything that it's written and nothing works.

**a)** I did a boot in my computer

**b)** Reinitialize my cell phone

**c)** Check all setups in `Developer options`:  `USB Debugger is On`, `Waiting for the debugger` and the app name in `Select an app to be debugger`

**d)** Use the option in *Android Studio*:  `Invalidate Caches and Restart`

**e)** Turn off the `minifyEnabled` option in the `Gradle (Module)` and
comment out the option `shrinkResources`

**f)** Comment out the option `proguardFiles`

Whan can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something that I've tried that has solved my problem, until the next time and then I wil do the same trick, without hesitation.

I've simply uninstalled the program completely on the cell phone.

As usual with *Android Studio*, it doesn't have logic, but I don't care, as long as it solves the problem